Any potential issues with using A/C duct sealant to seal corners of a garage door?
Does duct sealant shrink when curing? Specifically, does Red Devil 0841DS RD-DS 181 Acrylic Latex Duct Sealant shrink as it is drying?
I watched a youtube video where it was used to seal the corners of a garage door. I have the same garage door and the same gaps so trying to figure out any issues before I use this stuff.



Surface Recommendation ‎Metal

What are you trying to accomplish with this sealant?

trying to avoid dirt and debris getting blown in from lawn blower
